# Consultas entre tabelas com Eloquent - Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, modelo-relacional, laravel-eloquent

Boas, tenho o seguinte problema ao usar o Laravel 5 no relacionamento de tabelas:

Tenho estas 4 tabelas (nomes hipotéticos para ilustrar o problema):

[image: tabelas]

Usando os modelos do Laravel 5 relacionei-as entre elas:

**Modelo Empresa**

```
public function pessoa(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Pessoas')
}
```

**Modelo Pessoas**

```
public function trabalho(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Trabalho')
}
public function empresa(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Empresa')
}
```

**Modelo Trabalho**

```
public function custo(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Custo')
}
public function pessoa(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Pessoa')
}
```

**Modelo Custo**

```
public function trabalho(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Trabalho')
}
```

A minha dúvida é como conseguir fazer o somatório do custo de todas as pessoas de uma determinada empresa e de todos os trabalhos...
Por exemplo, para saber o custo total de um trabalho faço algo do género:

```
$trabalho = new Trabalho->find($id)
$custoDoTrabalho = $trabalho->custo->sum('montante')
```

Contudo se fizer o seguinte:

```
$pessoas = new Empresa->find($id)->pessoa
$custoDosTrabalhosTodasAsPessoas = $pessoas->trabalho->custo->sum('montante')
```

**Não funciona!**

Para atingir o resultado pretendido tenho de escrever muitas linhas (e eu sou preguiçoso e o projeto é grande e com muitos casos destes!)

```
$custo = 0;
$pessoas = new Pessoa->find($id);
$trabalhos = $pessoas->trabalho;
foreach($trabalhos as $trabalho)
      $custo+=$trabalho->custo->sum('montante')
```

Existe alguma forma de usar as relações "Eloquentes" para este objetivo, ou tenho mesmo de escrever tudo?

*(desculpem o texto tão grande... obrigado em avanço!)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> $pessoas = new Empresa->find($id)->pessoa
> $custoDosTrabalhosTodasAsPessoas = $pessoas->trabalho->custo->sum('montante')
> ```
>
> isso não funciona porque `$pessoas` é uma lista. o certo seria
>   `$pessoas[0]->trabalho->...`. Mas isso não resolveria teu problema no
>   geral.

Para resolver teu problema de fazer o somatório do custo de todas as pessoas de uma determinada empresa e de todos os trabalhos, da pra fazer apenas e uma consulta:

```
select sum(custos.montante) from empresas
join pessoas on (pessoas.empresa_id = empresas.id)
join trabalho on (trabalho.pessoa_id = pessoas.id)
join custos on (custos.trabalho_id = trabalho.id)
where empresas.id = ?
```

esse sql tu pode executar ele cru:

```
DB::statement('teu sql...');
```

mas usando eloquent pode fazer assim:

```
Empresa::
     join('pessoas', function($query){
         $query->on('pessoas.empresa_id','=','empresas.id') 
      })
      ->join('trabalho', function($query){
         $query->on('trabalho.pessoa_id','=','pessoas.id') 
      })
      ->join('custos',function($query){
         $query->on('custos.trabalho_id','=','trabalho.id') 
      })
     ->where('empresas.id','=',1)
     ->sum('custos.montante')
```

outra forma:

```
DB::table('empresas')
         ->join('pessoas', 'pessoas.empresa_id', '=', 'empresas.id')
         ->join('trabalho', 'trabalho.pessoa_id', '=', 'pessoas.id')
         ->join('custos', 'custos.trabalho_id', '=', 'trabalho.id')
         ->where('empresas.id','=',1)
         ->sum('custos.montante');
```

Comment: Já tinha colocado esta questão à bastante tempo, entretanto já resolvi o problema (já não me lembro bem como), mas gostei da sua solução e parece-me a mais correta! Obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: Já tinha colocado esta questão à bastante tempo, entretanto já resolvi o problema (já não me lembro bem como), mas gostei da sua solução e parece-me a mais correta! Obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score 1):

Não é preciso verificar por cada pessoa.. para somar todo o montante de todos os trabalhos:

```
$total = App\Custo::sum('montante');
```

Para somar o montante por trabalho:

```
$trabalhoTotal = App\Trabalho::find(1)->custo->sum('montante');
```

Ou:

```
$trabalhoTotal = App\Custo::where('trabalho_id',1)->sum('montante');
```

Comment: Pois neste caso funcionaria... mas expus mal o caso (está incompleto), pois ligado à tabela Pessoas existe outra (Empresas)... Ao fazer:
     $total = App\Custo::sum('montante');
Ficaria com o montante de todas as pessoas de todas as empresas... eu apenas quero o montante de todas as pessoas de uma determinada empresa... Vou editar a questão!

Comment: Como você quer que retorne? TrabalhoxCustos? EmpresaxTrabalhoxCusto? PessoaxCusto? @RicardoCruz

Comment: PessoaxCusto... A soma de todos os Custos de todos os Trabalhos realizados por todas as Pessoas numa determinada Empresa.