# Laravel / Eloquent - Consulta em mais de uma tabela

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho as seguintes `Tabelas/Models` e não estou conseguindo fazer uma consulta:

***Model 1***

```
id | Name
---+---------------
1  | Model1.1
2  | Model1.2
3  | Model1.3
```

---

***Model 2***

```
id | Name     | model1_id
---+----------+---------- 
1  | Model2.1 | 1
2  | Model2.2 | 2
3  | Model2.3 | 3
```

---

***Model 3***

```
id | Name     | model2_id
---+----------+---------- 
1  | Model3.1 | 1
2  | Model3.2 | 2
3  | Model3.3 | 3
```

---

```
class Model1 extends Model
{
   public $table = 'model1';

   const CREATED_AT = 'created_at';
   const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';
   protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
   public $fillable = ['name','model2_id'];
   protected $casts = ['name' => 'string'];
   public static $rules = [];

   public function model2()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Model2::class);
   }
}
```

---

```
class Model2 extends Model
{
   public $table = 'model2';

   const CREATED_AT = 'created_at';
   const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';
   protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
   public $fillable = ['name'];
   protected $casts = ['name' => 'string'];
   public static $rules = [];

   public function model1()
   {
      return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Model1::class);
   }

   public function model2()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Model2::class);
   }
}
```

---

```
class Model3 extends Model
{
   public $table = 'model3';

   const CREATED_AT = 'created_at';
   const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';
   protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
   public $fillable = ['name',];
   protected $casts = ['name' => 'string'];
   public static $rules = [];

   public function model2()
   {
      return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Model2::class);
   }
}
```

Com o exemplo abaixo não consegui pois o que preciso é saber os `Model1` que relacionados ao `Model3`.

```
$model1 = Model3::where('model2_id', 2);
```

Comment: Veja se isso pode te ajudar: [Consultas entre tabelas com Eloquent - Laravel 5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55283/consultas-entre-tabelas-com-eloquent-laravel-5)

Comment: Acho que isto resolve: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: Muito obrigado... ajudou bastante a resolver o problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>**Relacionamento N:M Laravel**</sub>

Os `models` estão configurado errado no item `fillable` faltou colocar os campos corretamente e as suas relações estão todas erradas, [vide documentação para maiores informações](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships) e o links abaixo com exemplos de como configurar os relacionamentos **1:1**, **1:N** e **N:M**:

- [Salvar relacionamento 1:1 no Laravel 5.3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175842/salvar-relacionamento-11-no-laravel-5-3)
- [Como usar o relacionamento hasmany no laravel 5.2?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173966/como-usar-o-relacionamento-hasmany-no-laravel-5-2)
- [Salvar varios atributos para um mesmo objeto no Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168781/salvar-varios-atributos-para-um-mesmo-objeto-no-laravel)

---

***Exemplo modificado***:

```
class Model1 extends Model
{
   public $table = 'model1';

   const CREATED_AT = 'created_at';
   const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';
   protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
   public $fillable = ['name'];
   protected $casts = ['name' => 'string'];
   public static $rules = [];

   public function model2()
   {
      return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Model2::class,'model1_id', 'id');
   }
}
```

---

```
class Model2 extends Model
{
   public $table = 'model2';

   const CREATED_AT = 'created_at';
   const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';
   protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
   public $fillable = ['name','model1_id'];
   protected $casts = ['name' => 'string'];
   public static $rules = [];

   public function model1()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Model1::class,'model1_id', 'id');
   }

   public function model3()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Model3::class,'model2_id', 'id');
   }
}
```

---

```
class Model3 extends Model
{
   public $table = 'model3';

   const CREATED_AT = 'created_at';
   const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';
   protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
   public $fillable = ['name','model2_id'];
   protected $casts = ['name' => 'string'];
   public static $rules = [];

   public function model2()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Model2::class,'model2_id','id');
   }
}
```

---

A pergunta eu fiquei um pouco na dúvida, mas, eu acho que é um simples `join` entre as tabelas:

> Com o exemplo abaixo não consegui, pois o que preciso é saber os `Model1` que relacionados ao `Model3`.

```
$model1 = Model1::join('model2','model2.model1_id','=','model1.id')
                ->join('model3','model3.model2_id','=','model2.id')
                ->where('model3.model2_id', 2)
                ->get();
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Laravel: defining-relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)
- [Soma da multiplicação da quantidade por valor do produto em vendas diarias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/244287/soma-da-multiplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-quantidade-por-valor-do-produto-em-vendas-diarias/244339#244339)
- [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Ajudou muito... consegui resolver o "problema" com todas as dicas.