# Laravel 5.8 - Podemos fazer sync em uma tabela pivot sem o campo id?

Tags: laravel, async

Tenho uma tabela **pivot** com o campo `user_id` e `article_id` (*muito para muitos*), digamos que tenho os seguintes registros:

```
1-2,
1-3,
1-4,
2-1,
2-2.
```

Em um certo momento o usuário 1 não quer mais estar ligado ao article 2 e também adiciona uma relação ao article 5, então eu teria 2 processos: deletar a relação `1-2` e adicionar a relação `1-5`, note que na tabela não tem o campo id.

Como se faz usando `sync`? Olhando a [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships) me parece que `sync` só funciona quando temos o campo id na tabela `pivot`?

***Não teria como deletar usando*** `where` `user_id=1` `AND` `article_id=2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Laravel 5.8 - Podemos fazer `sync` em uma tabela `pivot` sem o campo `id`?

O Eloquent Framework ORM contido no Laravel tem esse comando [sync](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models) que tem na sua documentação o seguinte texto:

- ***Using Sync To Attach Many To Many Models***

  > You may also use the sync method to attach related models. The sync method accepts an array of IDs to place on the pivot table. After this operation is complete, only the IDs in the array will be on the intermediate table for the model:

tradução google:

- ***Usando a sincronização para conectar muitos a muitos modelos***

  > Você também pode usar o método de sincronização para anexar modelos relacionados. O método de sincronização aceita uma matriz de IDs para colocar na tabela dinâmica. Após a conclusão da operação, somente os IDs na matriz estarão na tabela intermediária do modelo:

*Ou seja, em uma relação de muitos para muitos a função desse método é ajustar a relação na tabela `pivot` onde os códigos a serem excluídos e os códigos a serem inseridos são feitos de forma transparente.* Em uma analogia real é feito no método [sync](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models) um [detach](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables)(*que remove registro da relação*) e depois um [attach](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables)(*que adiciona registro a relação*).

Na tabela de relação não tem no modelo apresentado na documentação o `id`, nem é necessário, talvez campos extras com algum tipo de configuração pode coexistir, mas, as chave primária composta das duas relações.

***Exemplo:***

Um autor pode estar contido em vários livros e vice-versa livro pode ter vários autores:

```
class Autor extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'authors';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['nome'];

    //Relacionamento. N:M
    public function livros()
    {        
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Livro',
            'autor_livros', 
            'autor_id', 
            'livro_id'
        );
    }
}

class Livro extends Model
{    
    protected $table = 'books';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['titulo'];
    public  $timestamps = false;

    //Relacionamento. N:M
    public function autores()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Autor',
            'autor_livros',
            'livro_id',
            'autor_id'
        );
    }
}
```

Usando o método [sync](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models):

```
$livro = Livro::find(1);
$livro->autores()->sync(array(1,2));
```

ou

```
$autor = Autor::find(1);
$autor->livros()->sync(array(3,4));
```

<sup>***Ref.***</sup>

- [Laravel - Inserting Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models)
- [Laravel / Eloquent - Consulta em mais de uma tabela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/244376/54880)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode no model da sua tabela pivot informar qual o `primary key`, como abaixo:

```
class PivotModel extends Eloquent {
   public $incrementing = false;
   protected $primaryKey = [
    'user_id',
    'article_id'
   ];
}
```

Após isso é só fazer uma query removendo a partir do `user_id` e `article_id`, como abaixo:

```
$item = Pivot::where('article_id', 1)->where('user_id', 2)->first();
$item->delete();
```

Uma outra opção é utilizar os métodos `attach` e `detach` da seguinte maneira:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

$user->roles()->detach(3);
$user->roles()->attach(5);
```

Comment: eu não tenho model para pivot table. Poderia criar. Mas vc tem alguma sugestão usando o methodo sync e sem model?

Comment: Coloquei utilizando o attach e detach, acredito que é mais simples que usar o sync nesse caso.