# Como fazer relacionamento usando o resultado de um relacionamento com Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Estou com dificuldade para fazer o relacionamento entre a tabela `produtos`, `opções` e `tipos de opções` no Laravel, consigo trazer os produtos e suas opções usando `Product::with('options')->get()`, mas queria que as opções viessem com os tipos também.

Não sei se o erro está no Banco ou no relacionamento do Model, pois no Banco eu consigo trazer normalmente usando join.

**Observação:**

Cada produto pode ter varias opções que por sua vez tem vários tipos.

Exemplos de opções:

- "Tamanho",
- "Cor",
- "Peso".

Exemplos de Tipos de opções:

- "P",
- "Vermelho",
- "1kg".

**Tabelas:**

[image: Relacionamento das tabelas]

**Model Product:**

```
public function options()
{
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\ProductsOptions',
                  'products_has_options',
                  'id_product',
                  'id_option')
          ->withPivot('id');
}
```

**Model ProductsOptions:**

```
public function products_options_types()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\ProductsOptionsTypes',
                     'products_has_options_types',
                     'id_product_has_option',
                     'id_options_types');
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Laravel / Eloquent - Consulta em mais de uma tabela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/244308/laravel-eloquent-consulta-em-mais-de-uma-tabela)

Comment: Exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/376317/laravel-5-8-podemos-fazer-sync-em-uma-tabela-pivot-sem-o-campo-id/376867#376867

Comment: Exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/376867/54880

Comment: Exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/244308/laravel-eloquent-consulta-em-mais-de-uma-tabela/244376#244376

Comment: Esses campos `id` são somente para auto - incremento nas junções de muitos para muitos? se forem são desnecessários

Comment: Então, eu estava usando o id da tabela products_has_options no campo id_products_has_option da tabela products_has_options_types pois precisava relacionar a o tipo de opção com a opção do produto

Comment: Entendi, então é um pouco diferente todas essas relações e tem que criar um Entidade Model para cada tabela com chave primária e tudo. Você já implementou alguma coisa?